# Nutch conf/crawl-urlfilter.txt not found in Nutch 1.11

Tags: apache, solr, nutch

All, I was trying to setup [nutch 1.11](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/nutch/1.11/apache-nutch-1.11-bin.zip) in my Windows7 cygwin environment. Currently I am following [this guide](http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/building-a-search-engine-with-nutch-and-solr-in-10-minutes). But unfortunately the file `crawl-urlfilter.txt` mentioned in the read is not expected under the folder `conf`. It seems 1.11 doesn't have this file ? Did I miss something ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the author of the guide means this file:`conf/regex-urlfilter.txt` not this one: `conf/crawl-urlfilter.txt`

Hope this helps,

Le Quoc Do